# std::exception_ptr copy semantics

Tags: c++, exception

On cppreference `std::exception_ptr` is mentioned to having smart pointer like semantics.
However if i do the following it does behave like so.

```
std::exception_ptr ptr{};

auto l = [ptr] mutable {
   try{
      ...
   }catch(...){
       ptr = std::current_exception();
   }

};
```

If the code throws I would expect that ptr contains a copy of the exception and is visible outside of the lambda even though inside the lambda it is a copy.

Can someone advise on this?

Comment: "*and is visible outside of the lambda even though inside the lambda it is a copy.*" Um... why would you believe that? You captured it *by value*. This has nothing to do with the semantics of `exception_ptr`; it's just how lambda captures by value work. It'd be no different than a `T*` or a `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @NicolBolas if it was a shared_ptr the changes would be visible if i copied it by value. I know how by value works. It its referenced counted the count should increase by 1 when copied by value.

Comment: @BlairDavidson With a `shared_ptr` the changes also aren't visible. A by-value capture means the variable inside the lambda and the variable outside the lambda refer to different objects. https://godbolt.org/z/T6EhP35rv

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly ordinary pointer semantics. Assigning to a copy of a pointer doesn't change the original pointer or the object pointed to the original pointer.

Consider the equivalent of your code with `std::exception_ptr` replaced by `int*`.

```
int *ptr = nullptr;

auto l = [ptr]() mutable {
  // try {
  int *exception = new int(5); // allocate an "exception", mimicking how a throw allocates an exception object
  // } catch(...) {
  ptr = exception; // std::current_exception returns a pointer to the current exception... which in this analogy is just the value of "exception"
  // }
};
l();
```

After this block of code, what is `ptr`? It is still `nullptr`, because the assignment in `l` didn't modify `ptr`. It only modified `l`'s copy of `ptr`. `std::exception_ptr` behaves in the same way (and `std::shared_ptr`, too).

Presumably, you want to capture `ptr` by reference. Then storing something into `ptr` within `l` will have effects visible from outside.

```
std::exception_ptr ptr;
auto l = [&ptr]() {
    try { throw std::runtime_error("oops"); }
    catch(...) { ptr = std::current_exception(); }
};
l();

try { if(ptr) std::rethrow_exception(ptr); }
catch(std::exception const &e) { std::cerr << e.what() << "\n"; }
// prints "oops", doesn't work if [&ptr] is changed to [ptr]
```

Comment: I finally realized that what the OP is doing is exactly like `ptr = std::make_shared<int>(42);` in your godbolt link in the comment above. +1